# React Native 0.57.8: ram-bundle causes android runtime error: Could not get BatchedBridge in production app

Tags: android, react-native, bundle

I updated my react native app to use `ram-bundle`. The application loads and runs without issue on Android debug.

When I assemble a production release, it build without error. But when I run the app, I get the runtime error below. This happens on simulators and devices.

I have inspected the APK in Android Studio and it does contain the index.android.bundle.

**How should I go about debugging this issue**?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication 
    NativeRunnable.java:-2 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
    Handler.java:789 android.os.Handler.handleCallback
    Handler.java:98 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
    Looper.java:164 android.os.Looper.loop
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run
    Thread.java:764 java.lang.Thread.run


Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly 
    NativeRunnable.java:-2 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
    Handler.java:789 android.os.Handler.handleCallback
    Handler.java:98 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
    Looper.java:164 android.os.Looper.loop
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run
    Thread.java:764 java.lang.Thread.run
```